# Understanding code for LED light for stm32f334R8?

Tags: c, stm32, led

```
#include "stm32f30x_conf.h"

uint16_t read_pos(void);
void PC_Conf(void);
uint8_t get_bit(uint8_t, uint8_t);

// PROCESSORTACT = 64 MHz
// AHB  Prescaler = 1
// APB1 Prescaler = 2
// APB2 Prescaler = 1

long pin = 1;
long dir = 1;
char recvd;

int main(void){
    /*

    */
    //Definitions
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_Initstructure;
    TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure;
    NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_NVICInitStructure;

    //ENABLE CLOCK
    RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOB, ENABLE);
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM2, ENABLE);

    //GPIO
    GPIO_Initstructure.GPIO_Mode=GPIO_Mode_OUT;
    GPIO_Initstructure.GPIO_OType=GPIO_OType_PP;
    GPIO_Initstructure.GPIO_Pin=GPIO_Pin_All;
    GPIO_Initstructure.GPIO_PuPd=GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    GPIO_Initstructure.GPIO_Speed=GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_Initstructure);

    //TIMER
    TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_Prescaler = (64000-1); //TIM2 cycle to 1kHz
    TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_Period = 500; //Every 500ms
    TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM2,&TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure);

    //NVIC
    NVIC_NVICInitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel=TIM2_IRQn;
    NVIC_NVICInitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd=ENABLE;
    NVIC_NVICInitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority=0;
    NVIC_NVICInitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority=0;
    NVIC_Init(&NVIC_NVICInitStructure);

    //Enable everything
    TIM_Cmd(TIM2, ENABLE);
    TIM_ITConfig(TIM2, TIM_IT_Update, ENABLE);

  /* Infinite loop */
  while (1)
  {
  }
}

void TIM2_IRQHandler(void)
{   
    GPIOB->ODR &= 0;
    GPIOB->ODR ^=1<<pin;

    //Pin to new value
    if(dir == 1)
    {
        if(pin == 5)
            pin=11;
        else if(pin == 15)
        {   pin-=1;
            dir = 0;
        }
        else
            pin+=1;
    }
    else
    {
        if(pin == 11)
            pin = 5;
        else if(pin == 1)
        {
            pin+=1;
            dir = 1;
        }
        else
            pin-=1;
    }

    TIM_ClearITPendingBit(TIM2,TIM_IT_Update);
}
```

I have trouble understanding this code. First part is okay, but I don't understand the last function.

Can someone explain me simply what is going on in the last part of this code in `TIM2_IRQHandler(void)`?

I am new in this, any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

In many interrupts you need to clear the interrupt pending flag. If you don't when you exit from the handler, the interrupt will be called again. Every interrupt is described in the Reference manual of your micro. For example SPI interrupt pending flag is cleared by writing or reading from the DR register. Another one requires that bit to be cleared by the programmer.

The rule of thumb: clear the flag as soon as you enter the interrupt.

If the interrupt can be triggered by more than one event, the programmer should check which one was the source of the exception.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Can you shortly explain me these if statements, what means dir,pin and why excatly 15,11,5..?

Comment: Yes - it actually toggles the uC's pin defined in the pin variable. on the first iteration it will be PB1, then PB2 .. PB4 id pin == 5 it jumps to the PB11 and continues to PB15 when it has to change the direction. dir is for incrementing or decrementing the pin value. So when pin reaches 15 dir changes to  0 and pin-- is executed instead of pin++.

Comment: Ok understood. I hope you can answer me on one more question. Line with prescaler TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_Prescaler = (64000-1); Why 64000 and why -1?